# Autofac DI migration to ASP.NET Core DI

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I've got function that resolves service by using autofac IComponentContext Resolve

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly())
          .AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.AddDispatchers();
    }
```

builder.AddDispatchers():

```
 public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddDispatchers(this ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<CommandDispatcher>().As<ICommandDispatcher>();
        builder.RegisterType<Dispatcher>().As<IDispatcher>();
        builder.RegisterType<QueryDispatcher>().As<IQueryDispatcher>();
    }
}
```

It's dynamicaly choosing Handler by it's type

```
public class QueryDispatcher : IQueryDispatcher
{
    private readonly IComponentContext _context;

    public QueryDispatcher(IComponentContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<TResult> QueryAsync<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));

        dynamic handler = _context.Resolve(handlerType);

        return await handler.HandleAsync((dynamic)query);
    }
}
```

What should I do to migrate that to inbuilt ASP.NET Core DI?

Comment: Your question needs more focus. What have you tried? What doesn't work? What is the part you have trouble migrating? Please be as specific as possible.

Comment: Actually I've done the same that Ricardo suggested, but still getting an error:
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: Since it seems you require Batch-Registration, why do you want to switch from Autofac to MS.DI anyway. Autofac has built-in Batch-Registration support, while MS.DI does not.

Answer (score 0):

Register:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ICommandDispatcher, CommandDispatcher>();
    services.AddScoped<IDispatcher, Dispatcher>();
    services.AddScoped<IQueryDispatcher, QueryDispatcher>();
}
```

Inject:

```
public class QueryDispatcher : IQueryDispatcher
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

    public QueryDispatcher(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public async Task<TResult> QueryAsync<TResult>(IQuery<TResult> query)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)
            .MakeGenericType(query.GetType(), typeof(TResult));

        dynamic handler = _serviceProvider.GetService(handlerType);

        return await handler.HandleAsync((dynamic)query);
    }
}
```

Note: I am using lifetime scoped because you didn't provide any indication as to the desired lifetime, but you can also use `AddSingleton` or `AddTransient`.

Comment: I've tried that, but then I'm getting a error:
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

Comment: Ah, you need to register IQueryHandler<,> too

Comment: Yes, but I have like 8 to 10 Handlers, and It's a lot of registrating then cos I have to register each one of them.
But for Autofac I could do it just one time inside the QueryDispatcher

Comment: No, you register the open type

Comment: I mean, typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)

Comment: services.AddSingleton<typeof(IQueryHandler<,>), typeof(???)>();
My Handlers are implementations of IQueryHandler, What should I add there?

Comment: Yeah, that won't work, you need to register each one individually. IMO, the best thing for you is to use Scrutor: https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor.

Comment: Like this?

`services.Scan(scan => scan
                .FromAssemblyOf<IQueryDispatcher>()
                    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IQueryDispatcher>())
                        .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                        .WithScopedLifetime()
                    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>)))
                        .AsImplementedInterfaces());`

Still have Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference am I doing it wrong?

Comment: That's right. The problem is that your service is not being resolved, that is, GetService is returning null. See this https://github.com/khellang/Scrutor/issues/68, might help.

Comment: Can I contact you? Still have some questions about this problem